# XFCE Panel Plugin API

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

Developers.
Does anyone know about XFCE Panel Plugin API? I want to create my own panel plugin and don't know about the API.
Which programming language is needed? Where should the files be located?
I really need to know please help!

Comment: https://ecc-comp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/a-simple-tutorial-for-xfce-panel-plugin.html

Comment: @MarkKirby I already checked that. I need more details, Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xfce Panel support two types of plugins:

Internal: are loadable modules, using the GModule interface.

External. are separate programs that are embedded into the panel using the GtkPlug and GtkSocket mechanism.

In order to handle these plugins the plugin system was entirely rewritten, along with the rest of the panel framework.

The API documentation is installed with the panel and also available from:

http://www.xfce.org/documentation/api/

[Source](https://wiki.xfce.org/dev/howto/panel_plugins)

Answer (score 1):

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce)

> Xfce is based on the GTK+ toolkit.

See [gtk.org/language-bindings](https://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php).

Next, you can search for this:

> Together with GtkSocket, GtkPlug provides the ability to embed widgets from one process into another process in a fashion that is transparent to the user.